# Why my array wont print what it got in the while loop after the while loop is broken?

Tags: php

I am trying to add values (an input from the user) to an array in a while loop but it won't print it after the loop itself.

```
<?php
$x = 1;

while(!isset($_POST['stopButton'])) {

  $countryArr[$x] = $searchCountry;
  $message = "added!";
  echo "<script>
    alert('$message');
    window.location.href='../html/choicePage.php';
  </script>";
  $x++;
}

foreach($countryArr as $country) {
  echo $country;
}
?>
```

Comment: `while(!isset($_POST['stopButton'])) {` - how is this supposed to work? I claim that your code is never adding anything to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, but this sounds like you lack knowledge of the most essential basic workings of a PHP web application to begin with. If you are expecting that array to “survive” across multiple requests (so that you could add items by having the user submit them one after the other, one each time), you’d be fundamentally wrong already. You would need to store that data on the server side between requests then, for example using sessions.

Comment: If this would work, where's `$searchCountry` set?

Comment: This code is incomplete. Where is `$_POST['stopButton']` set? Are you submitting a form? And where is `$searchCountry` coming from? Anyway, this whole concept is flawed. Even if you get as far as the foreach loop, it will echo a series of script blocks. But when that is delivered to the browser, it will run the first script block, which contains an instruction to redirect to another page. Therefore the other script blocks will never be seen or used.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what functionality you're trying to achieve here, but you certainly need to think of a better way of doing it. If you explain your overall requirement then perhaps we can make something which will be useful and usable.

Comment: P.S. `while(!isset($_POST['stopButton'])) {` is totally illogical. You can't wait for this value to be set. It will either be set when the request comes to the server, or it won't. If it isn't set, then your code will cause an infinite loop while it "waits" for something which can never happen. The value cannot be set again until the user makes another request to the server (and this will cause a new instance of the PHP script to be executed - see below.)

Comment: As misorude says, I think you fundamentally don't understand how the web works. Make sure you are clear about how the request/response lifecyle of a HTTP application works. The PHP does not sit there running permanently (unlike in a desktop app). Instead it runs the script again for each incoming request. Each time the script runs, it runs as if it had never run before, it has no knowledge of previous requests. All variables are reset. This is what is called a _stateless_ application. (You can add state by using Session, or storing data in a database, etc, but it isn't automatically there.)

Answer (score -1):

Please see the comments I added

```
<?php
$x = 1;

while(!isset($_POST['stopButton'])) { // this runs if no form post stopButton

  $countryArr[$x] = $searchCountry;    // $searchCountry is undefined
  $message = "added!";
  echo "<script>
    alert('$message');
    window.location.href='../html/choicePage.php';
  </script>";
  $x++;
}    // it's still not posted, never will be in this request, so this will keep looping

foreach($countryArr as $country) { // you only an array of empty strings, but won't reach here
  echo $country;
}
```